# Getting place holder value from resource path in REST?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, java-ee-7

I am using Jersey RESTful web services. I have below resource.

```
@Path("/banker/{location}")
@Component
public class BankResource{  

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Override
    public Response getBankerByID(@PathParam("id") String id) {

          //some logic

      }


}
```

In above class how can i get the value of **{location}** ? Because based on **{location}** value i need to do some processing. Is it possible to get its value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location value using @PathParam and map it to method parameter as follows.
`

```
@Path("/banker/{location}")
@Component
public class BankResource{  

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Override
    public Response getBankerByID(@PathParam("location") String location,
@PathParam("id") String id) {
   //your code here
}
```

`